Elastic benstalk, nginx config different for each environment
I have a .platform hook for the nginx config, the issue it is that I need a different configuration for each environment, for example in prod I do not want to use certboot, but for development I want, how can I deploy a different nginx config file depending on the environment?,
This is my nginx.conf file :
events {}
http {
    server {

        
        listen      80;
        server_name ~^(.+)$;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;


         # root directive should be global
        root /var/www/html/webroot;
        index index.html index.php;

       
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;

        location / {
            try_files $uri \$uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

    }
    client_max_body_size 100M;

}

(I would like to add a conditional depending on the environment to add the certboot cert. something like this: )
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
# RSA certificate
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

